# What do you call the early days of flu recovery

Tags: single-word-requests, phrases, phrase-requests

Is there a word for the first day or two that you start to feel better after having the flu, or something like that, fairly sick and feverish for 3-5 days.

That period when you are well enough to realize how out of sorts your life is, but not quite well enough to really do anything but futilely putter about not actually putting anything really back in order.  And every time you try you start to feel sick again.

(if you can't tell that is my current state)

Thank you,

Answer (score 8):

I suggest **convalescence** which the [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/convalescence) gives as

> *noun*
>   the process or period of resting in order to get better after an illness or operation

with an example

> During convalescence, great care is necessary to protect the patient from taking cold.

Answer (score 0):

The [synonym](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/convalescence) to **convalescence** is **recuperation**.

Recuperation also means *process of getting better, rehabilitation, return to health, healing, rallying.*

Meaning: Recover from illness or exertion. https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/recuperate

Usage:

> > 1. ‘Carlos was dancing with English National Ballet but recuperating from a foot operation and had gone home to convalesce.’
> > 2. ‘He's still recuperating from his tracheotomy and his flu.’

Here is the [comparison](https://wikidiff.com/convalesce/recuperate) between Convalesce and Recuperate.

[image]